# cakephp how to set base path

Tags: cakephp, app-config

How do I set the root of the application?

What I mean, is that when I work locally, everything is under the root of my local website (i.e www.in cake.local/).

Now I made an application that will not be at the root of a website (i.e. www.outsite.com/sciences/biology/here_is_my_app).

Is there a way to make absolute URL in my app point to the app directory and not to the root of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that www.outside.com is pointing to directory www.outside.com/ on Your hosting.
Putting Your app in www.outside.com/sciences/biology/ directory should do the trick.

Comment: Arghh, It didn't work cause I didn't use htmlhelper to write links.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the HTML [base](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag to achieve this, set it to Route::url('/');